# Twitter requestAccessToAccountsWithType granted false

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter api on my iOS device.
To get access to the current logged in Twitter account, I use this piece of code:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
```

This works absolutely fine on my iPhone and granted is YES. However, when I try to build on my iPad, granted is NO. I am logged in on Twitter on both my iPhone and iPad, and my app is granted to use my account in my iPad settings.

When I log the localized description of the NSError, I got this:

> No access plugin was found that supports the account type com.apple.twitter

Can't find anything on google for this error. 
Who can help me out? I already deleted the app and logged out my Twitter account on my iPad.

Bug report **rdar://16656440** was opened for this issue.

Comment: Are you ensuring that your `ACAccountStore` object is not deallocated before the request completes?

Comment: Yep.. Would get a nullpointer otherwise too. And this is the way every single tutorial describes :(

Comment: Which iOS versions do your devices have?

Comment: Make sure to open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com and post the bug report number here so people can clone it if necessary.

Comment: @Rivera iOS 7.1 on both the iPhone and iPad.

Comment: @Leo Natan: I submitted the bug, onder report number 16656440

Comment: Do you have a console log from the device?

Comment: @harmjanr were you able to resolve this? Im facing the same error for iOS8

Comment: Any Solution???